# Routing with a default document

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I'm really having a hard time getting my head around routing. This has probably been asked before but I couldn't find it or didn't ask the right way...

I am porting over an existing classic asp site and beginning by adding an admin dashboard.  What I need is for when a user simply enters the site name the default document (default.asp) gets loaded, however if they enter {site}/Admin then routing takes over.  My default route controller is called "AdminController" and I have my project set up to start in /Admin.  This works, but anything else doesn't, unless I fall back to the basic default route that comes with a new project.

Desires:

1. {site} -> {site}/default.asp
2. {site}/Admin -> Admin/Index action
3. {site}/Admin/Shops -> Shops/Index action
4. {site}/Admin/Shops/Edit/{id} -> Shops/Edit(id) action

Here is my routing, I'm stuck somewhere:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditShop", // Route name
            "Shops/Edit/{slug}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Shops",
                action = "Edit",
                slug = ""
            } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Shops", // Route name
            "Admin/Shops/", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Shops",
                action = "Index"
            } // Parameter defaults
        );

        // default route for this app
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin", // Route name
            "Admin/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );

       //  default route for this app (this works for all cases except default.asp)
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

        routes.MapRoute("NothingMatched", "{*url}",
                        new {controller = "Error", action = "Http404"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you mapped the EditShop to Shops/Edit. That should probably be mapped to Admin/Shops/Edit to achieve what you want. I don't see any problem with the other route, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that got me going.  Still having trouble getting the default page to load without explicitly specifying.  Tried creating a PageRouteHandler() with no luck.  There must be a way to tell IIS to use routing except when a default page can be loaded.

Comment: we are having the same problem - if no routes are specified or matching iis should look for the default document! hopefully soon will...